# Javascript String operations

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Javascript has a number of string manipulation operations which can be performed on it. So we have methods like concat(), slice(), match(), etc

My question is do all these string manipulation methods return a new string value as the result OR are there some methods which actually modify the actual string being used in the method ?

Comment: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_02.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in JavaScript (and many other languages) are implemented as immutable objects. This has a few beneficial properties:

1. It's thread safe, and more specifically,
2. Multiple references to the same string can be kept safely without having to worry that the value changes.

This also means that *all* string methods must return a new string if they aim to modify the original value.

Comment: You can verify this very easily. Try to run `String.prototype.mutate = function (arg) { this = 'changed' }` and JS interpreters will complain that you are supplying an invalid left-hand side in assignment.

Comment: @LimH. That's not actually unique to `String`. `this` can't be set in any `function` as it's [not a variable](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.1).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski oh wow. Yet another time I completely misunderstood JS

Answer (score 0):

The return value is a clone of the original string.

In other words, calling `concat, match` or `slice` will not modify the original string.

You can always refer to the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) for documentation

But, to quote from the source

**Concat**

Combines the text of two or more strings and returns a **new string**.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, and once they are created they even cannot be modified again.

[Mdn:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Data_structures#Strings)

> Unlike in languages like C, JavaScript strings are immutable. This means that once a string is created, it is not possible to modify it. However, it is still possible to create another string based on an operation on the original string, for example, a substring of the original (by picking individual letters or using String.substr()) or a concatenation of two strings using the concatenation operator (+) or String.concat().

Therefore, yes. Every String operation returns a new String